# How can I remove fields '_index' and '_score' from my opensearch dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd, opensearch, configmap

I am using this in the fluend configuration:

```html
<filter **>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    # Enrich the logs with Kubernetes metadata
    pod_namespace ${record["kubernetes"]["namespace_name"]}
    pod_instance ${record["kubernetes"]["labels"]["app.kubernetes.io/instance"]}
    environment ${record["kubernetes"]["labels"]["environment"]}
    application_name ${record["kubernetes"]["labels"]["app.kubernetes.io/name"]}
    pod_name ${record["kubernetes"]["pod_name"]}
  </record>
  # Remove unneeded/redundant keys from fluent-bit that were already parsed or used for log enrichment
  # Additionally remove keys containing sensitive data
  remove_keys kubernetes,logtag,stream,_index,_score
</filter>
```

all the fields like kubernetes, stream, log are removed, but _index, and _score are still there. what can I do to remove those?